# Laravel artisan migrate command not working

Tags: laravel

after generating migration and ran the migrate command (`php artisan migrate`) I saw this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Admin_Create_Galleries' not found in /var/www/sampleapp/laravel/cli/tasks/migrate/resolver.php on line 121
```

I have no idea in this error, after searching on resolver.php, I found no "Admin_Create_Galleries" word on resolver.php. Could you help me with this errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file will be referred to in your migrations table in your database - if you no longer have that file, or changed the name, you should update it in the migrations table.

Note: normally it is better to either roll back a migration, or do another migration, rather than editing the migration itself.

Comment: Actually there is a file name Admin_Create_Galleries.php in a bundle migration folder. Someone has reset migration and changed the name of its class accidentally. BTW thanks for your answer.